# Find a Matrix which projects vectors onto the given plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

> Consider a plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ which intersects the origin and is orthogonal to
> $$
> \mathbf{v}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1 \\
> -2 \\
> 1
> \end{array}\right)
> .$$
>
> (a) Find a $3 \times 3$ matrix $P_{\mathbf{v}}$ which projects vectors onto this plane.
> $\tag{5 marks }$
>
> (b) Given the matrix $P_{\mathbf{v}}$ from part (a), describe the geometric significance of the (nonlinear) function $f(\mathbf{w})=\sqrt{\mathbf{w}^{T} P_{\mathbf{v}} \mathbf{w}}$.
> $\tag{5 marks }$

[transcribed from screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KknQ4.png)

**My attempt :** The plane which is orthogonal to the vector $x =\left ( \begin{matrix}
    1  \\
    -2  \\
     1   \\
   \end{matrix} \right )$  is $x-2y+z = 0.$

Now the points on this plane belongs to this set - $\{ c_1\left ( \begin{matrix}
    2  \\
    1  \\
     0   \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) +  c_2\left ( \begin{matrix}
    0  \\
    1  \\
    2   \\
   \end{matrix} \right ) : c_1 , c_2 \in \mathbb R\}$ . $\left ( \begin{matrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    1   \\
   \end{matrix} \right )$ also belongs to this set.

So we can say the matrix which projects all the vectors on the plane $x-2y+z = 0$ is $\left ( \begin{matrix}
    0  & 2 &1\\
    1  & 1 & 1\\
    2  & 0 & 1\\
   \end{matrix} \right ) $

Because $\left ( \begin{matrix}
    1 & -2 & 1 
   \end{matrix} \right ) \times \left ( \begin{matrix}
    0  & 2 &1\\
    1  & 1 & 1\\
    2  & 0 & 1\\
   \end{matrix} \right ) \times \left ( \begin{matrix}
    x  \\
    y  \\
    z   \\
   \end{matrix} \right )= 0$  for all $ x, y , z \in \mathbb R$

Can anyone please check if my solution is correct and give some hints for the second part ?

Comment: It is from my assignment. Can you please check my solution?@JCAA

Comment: The solution is wrong: the projection of $(1,1,1)^T$ onto the plane should be itself but it is not.

Comment: "marks" might indicate that this assignment is "live" and for "real world points"

Comment: You have two answers. You should either accept one or say what else is needed. Otherwise the question looks unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a basis $\beta$ for a $2-$dimensional subspace $W$ conatined in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you should put these two vectors in the columns of a matrix $A$ and then compute $$P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$ It turns out that this matrix is the matrix of the transformation that projects vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $W$.

The column space of the matrix you provided, namely $$\left ( \begin{matrix}
    0  & 2 &1\\
    1  & 1 & 1\\
    2  & 0 & 1\\
   \end{matrix} \right )$$ is in fact the plane $\{x-2y+z=0\}\cap\mathbb{R}^3$ but it doesn't act on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by projecting vectors onto this plane. Can you see why? For a hint on part (b), I suggest you draw a picture and use the fact that $$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}=||\vec{u}||\times ||\vec{v}||\times\cos(\theta)$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.